# get appwidget width

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I would like to create a background bitmap dynamically for my appwidget. I've read that cell sizes are not the same on different devices so I dont want to use constant values for width and height of the bitmap.

Is there a way to retrieve the actual size of my appwidget?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use 9-patch images in situations like this.

Comment: I use 9-patch, but i want to add a colorfilter.

Comment: Well, Im using 160dp X 100dp now, but I assume there will be strange results on some devices :S